# "... when it comes time."

Tags: expressions

I came across this phrase in a business document:

> We will house both applications you send to your customers and applications you receive from your suppliers on your XXXX account. This will be clearly managed for you **when it comes time.**

Does this make grammatical sense? My whole life I've only heard  "... when the time comes"

Comment: This sentence, without further context, sounds confused to me.  It is not clear what any part of it means.

Comment: Well ignoring the business jargon, I'm interested in the second sentence "This will be clearly managed for you when it comes time"—the meaning comes across fairly clearly, I'm just not sure if it's technically grammatical.

Comment: Most hits on a Google search for "when it comes time" have a to-infinitive immediately after the expression; a few have 'for + noun ...'. These are certainly idiomatic. Is your example 'grammatical'? I'm pretty sure that there would be a split decision if the acceptability was voted on by a large usage panel, but that most if not all on the panel would consider there to be no real problem in an informal register. In a formal text, some might prefer 'when the time comes' (I would use this). Note, however, that  if one considers 'when the time comes' an acceptable deleted ...

Comment: form, one would have to do a lot of analysis on the acceptability of various types of deletion before rejecting 'when it comes time' on 'grammatical' grounds. It's far safer looking at how often a deletion is used (which the analysis would have to do anyway). // Google results for a search on "when it comes time" -"when it comes time to" -"when it comes time for" seem totally unhelpful.

Comment: It sounds idiomatic to me...but I must say that both this phrase and your suggested replacement sound very odd to me without any qualifying phrase after (e.g. *when it comes time **to fill out the forms*** or *when the time comes **to review your account***); in their bare form, I think of both as **euphemisms for death**. This seems like a connotation to avoid in a business setting.

Comment: It is not wrong, and it means basically the same as "when the time comes".

Answer (score -1):

> This will be clearly managed for you when it comes time.

The above is the phrase in question--whether "when it comes time" is incorrect or unidiomatic.

I agree that "when the time comes" is more familiar.  However, "when it comes time" can be short for "when it comes time" to do something--e.g., when it comes time to reconcile accounts, to pay taxes, or whatever.

Without more context it does seem odd, but I don't find it unidiomatic or incorrect.

Here's a quotation (from quote site):

> At the end of the day, **when it comes time** to make that decision, as
>   president, all you have to guide you are your values, and your vision,
>   and the life experiences that make you who you are. Michelle Obama

From https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/m/michelleob449066.html

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when%20it%20comes%20time%20*%2Cwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cwhen%20it%20comes%20time%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwhen%20it%20comes%20time%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhen%20it%20comes%20time%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20we%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20they%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhen%20the%20time%20comes%20when%3B%2Cc0)

Here are links to specific contemporary examples of the use of "when it comes time" not followed by "to + V," thanks to @Hot Licks in comments.

[community.babycenter.com/post/a66644842/…](http://community.babycenter.com/post/a66644842/%E2%80%A6)

[spwickstrom.com/doubt](http://spwickstrom.com/doubt)

[goodreads.com/book/show/1873060.The_Go_Giver](http://goodreads.com/book/show/1873060.The_Go_Giver)

[laurengreutman.com/gardening-with-raised-beds](http://laurengreutman.com/gardening-with-raised-beds)

Comment: '[S]eem[s] odd' but 'I don't find it unidiomatic '? 'When it comes time to make that decision, ...' I'd consider neither odd-sounding nor unidiomatic. But one really needs to give examples of the stand-alone usage 'when it comes time.'.

Comment: "When the time comes" seems just as in need of additional detail as "when it comes time," as though there's a later even (death or disability, perhaps) when "this" "will be clearly managed for you".

Comment: I wasn't asking about the need for retrievable information but about the frequency with which  'when it comes time' is used without 'to + V' or 'for + N etc'. I'd assume 'when the occasion arises' is used a lot more often than 'when the time arises', and that 'when it comes occasion' is quite rare.

Comment: https://community.babycenter.com/post/a66644842/how-not-to-offend-my-doctor

Comment: http://www.spwickstrom.com/doubt/

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1873060.The_Go_Giver

Comment: http://www.laurengreutman.com/gardening-with-raised-beds/